# How to handle disposal of paint?

Tags: painting

I usually have a little mug or can that I dip my paintbrush in when I want to clean it, but I found out it is not allowed to pour it out in the sink because water colors and acrylic paint is toxic.

It seems you have to drive to the recycling center and leave the can in there and write a note on it what is inside. I don't understand the details of this yet...

I don't have hundreds of cans with lids lying around at home, so how do you professionals handle this?

I don't know if you buy special disposable cans or something, and I don't know how many times it is possible to reuse the dirty water, after a while I doubt the brush will get any cleaner from it...